# Android PHP connection through Java

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am a beginner in android.I have built an application for login for leave module.For connecting it with mySql through PHP..I tried this code from a website.

```
package com.example.axdroid;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Axdroid extends Activity {
Button b;
EditText et,pass;
TextView tv;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_axdroid);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01); 
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Axdroid.this, "",
                   "Validating user...", true);
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Userpage.class);
             startActivity(i);                
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        login();                         
                    }
                  }).start();         

        }
        });}
void login(){
    try{           

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.222/AndroidLeave/check.php");
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Axdroid.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Userpage.class));
        }else{
            showAlert();               
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public void showAlert(){
    Axdroid.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Axdroid.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
            builder.setMessage("User not Found.") 
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       }
                   });                    
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();              
        }
    });
}

}
```

I am unable to make this work as while debugging the code...the control jumps from httpclient to catch code.Would appreciate any help in sorting this.

This is the PHP file.I have checked it seperately and it is working.

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="mydatabase";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$query_search = "select * from tbl_user where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
if($rows == 0) {
echo "No Such User Found";
}
else  {
echo "User Found";
}
?>
```

@ashwani
This is the present Axdroid.java page(main activity page)

```
public class Axdroid extends Activity {
Button b;
EditText et,pass;
TextView tv;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_axdroid);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01); 
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String url="http://192.168.1.222/AndroidLeave/check.php";
            JSONParser jparser= new JSONParser();
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "getcategory"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", et.getText().toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass.getText().toString()));
            JSONObject jObj= jparser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);try {
                String success = jObj.get("success").toString();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               


        }
        });}'
```

Comment: Please put your php file also .So, its better to find error

Comment: this is the PHP file..I have checked it seperately and its working.

Comment: Whether is it print on console or not ? System.out.println("Response : " + response); and print then which string print ?

Comment: I have added the PHP file.Kindly have a look at it.the response should be either "user not found" or "user found".

Comment: please post the message you get when exception is generated. The "e.getMessage()" part

Comment: The control is not entering e.getMessage() part...there is an error called sorce file nt attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for parsing the data I use the following class

JsonParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";

    public JSONParser() {
    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

            Log.d("reader value in json parser", reader.toString());
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("line in JsonParser", line);
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.d("Json value", json);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {

            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            json = "";
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

now in your activity try to pass a url like this

```
String url="place your url here";
JSONParser jparser= new JSONParser();
params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "getcategory"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username.getText().toString()));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));
JSONObject jobj= jparser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
```

//now here retrieve the data from json as:

```
String success= jobj.get("success");
```

Hope this helps!

also in your php file you have to use the `json_encode` function before `echo` !

Comment: Thank you @Ashwani...I had few questions, am sorry for the ignorance as am new to this.1)the JsonParser class should be added in src file  seperately in the android file right? 2) And the class defined is called in the activity.java page? I will try your solution and come back.Thank you

Comment: Ans 1). yes make a separate class named JSONParser in src folder . Ans 2) Call the makeHttpRequest function in the axdroid.java as it is in your question

Comment: in this jobj.get("pass the tag as same as from php");

Comment: in php try like this
$response["success"] = 0;
if($rows == 0) {
echo json_encode($response);
}
else  {
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
}

Comment: As your instruction, I havce made changes in php file also but I m getting the error as 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String' for the instruction    ' String success = jObj.get("success");'

Comment: just convert the jobj.get("success") into string like jobj.get("success").toString(); success will contain value 1 or 0 in string format .

Comment: yes added the the method toString()..   Now I m getting the error as Unhandled exception type JSONException

Comment: I have added try and catch block.It shows "variable success is not used".I tried running the whole code after building it. this is my main axdroid.java code '

Comment: use the variable success to check it have value 1 or 0 . Your problem to connect php form java has already been solved . Please accept the answer. thanks.

Comment: if you are testing your application in a emulator use 10.0.2.2 instead. see here http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: thank you very much for your patience...I just changed the url to 10.0.2.2 for the code i have initialially posted....and i am getting connection to the PHP......further...m not able to get to the database...but its a good start for me..

Comment: One query what does"10.0.2.2" stand for....and how ca it be changed for using it on a device?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function .  Changes according to your requirement.

```
void login()
        {
            String data = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            StringBuilder sb;
            String result;

            try
            {
                HttpClient httpsClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.4/check.php");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValue = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValue.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "" + et.getText().toString()));
                nameValue.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "" + pass.getText().toString()));


                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValue));


                HttpResponse httpRes = httpsClient.execute(httpPost);


                HttpResponse httpResponce = httpsClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponce.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }
            catch(Exception e) {}


             try
                {
                    BufferedReader BufR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(BufR.readLine() + "\n");
                    String line = "0";

                    while((line = BufR.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }


                    result = sb.toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(result.equals("User Found"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Found ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Not Found ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in convert String" + e.toString());
                }





        }
```

Comment: .I tried this code...The control jumped from "is" to "Log.e" and i am gettin an error.

Comment: do you change path and give internet permission .

Comment: Thankyou for the response..I downloaded the code and run it.Dint understand Nothing is happening.If you could kindly elaborate.

Comment: When i click on the button it should show a response right?It is not showing.

Comment: change database path  , import database then check . It 110 % work !!

Comment: Thank you i have mported the database and changed the database path.I am getting user not found for all the inputs and it is showing an xml file everytime the button is clicked.

Comment: Sorry to be not following.I gave admin it still shows the same result

Comment: I am able to run it on emulator now.Thanks.How do i run it on device....10.0.2.2 is not helping.

Comment: I think you are new in android . I gave you complete demo still you are not able to do this !!!

Comment: Yes i am new to android...as i mentioned its working on emulator....but nt on the device..